# Angular testing: why put component under test in providers?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

In the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-test-basics) it has an example where the component being tested is placed in the providers section of `TestBed.configureTestingModule` alongside the dependent service. They then use `TestBed.get` instead of `TestBed.createComponent` to access the component:

**app/welcome/welcome.component.spec.ts (class-only setup)**

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    // provide the component-under-test and dependent service
    providers: [
      WelcomeComponent,
      { provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService }
    ]
  });
  // inject both the component and the dependent service.
  comp = TestBed.get(WelcomeComponent);
  userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
});
```

Most of the other documentation and tutorials I see place the component under declarations.

When would I want to put the component under test in providers and why?

Comment: So, I tested this approach and it works... surprisingly. Good question.

Comment: injector will create the component just same as service.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation it's mentioned that if the `component-under-test` has some DI, then we need to create the component like this. It will create an instance of the Component, similar to how an instance of service is created. You can get this component using `TestBed.get(ComponentName)` and test the component.